# Determining $u$ and $v'$ from integration by parts for $\int \sin^2(5x)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a quick question, what would $u$ and $v'$ be if you were to integrate by parts for
$$\int \sin^2(5x)\,dx $$
For some reason, I am having trouble grasping how to choose $u$ and $v'$ so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't integrate by parts. Linearize the $\sin^2$.

Comment: why would you try to integrate that by parts? you can use $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$, $\cos^2 t = \frac{\cos(2t) + 1}{2}$ and $u$ substitution.

Comment: @LucasHenrique, the textbook says that you need to find u and v'. My first thought was to use the cos^2(x) identity but it specifically states to find u and v'. This is why I am lost because I would use substitution but it's asking to find u and v'......

Comment: If you want to evaluate this integral using by parts, set $u=\sin(5x)$ and $v'=\sin(5x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If we do integration by parts we have

$$\int \underbrace{\sin(5x)}_{u} \cdot \underbrace{\sin(5x)}_{v^{'}} \, dx=\underbrace{-\frac15\cdot \cos(5x)}_{v^{}}\cdot \underbrace{\sin(5x)}_{u}-\int \underbrace{5\cdot \cos(5x)}_{u^{'}}\cdot \underbrace{(-\frac15\cdot \cos(5x)}_{ v})\, dx$$

$$\int \sin(5x) \cdot \sin(5x) \, dx=-\frac15\cdot \cos(5x)\cdot \sin(5x)+\int \cos^2(5x) \, dx$$

Using Pythagorean trigonometric identity.

$$\int \sin(5x) \cdot \sin(5x) \, dx=-\frac15\cdot \cos(5x)\cdot \sin(5x)+\int 1-\sin^2(5x) \, dx$$

$\vdots$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not know why I didn't think of splitting the sin^2(5x) into sin(5x)*sin(5x)

Comment: For me it was very obvious. Experience is often helpful. You´re welcome.